# How to import `locize/translation-check` only in development env

Tags: javascript, dependencies, eslint

I'm using `locize/translation-check` to have a minimal UI to manage translations in development mode.

Running ESLint, it reports me an error:

```
   5:1   error  'translation-check' should be listed in the project's dependencies, not devDependencies  import/no-extraneous-dependencies
```

It is right!

In fact, I use `locize/translation-check` this way (simplified component):

```js
...
import { showTranslations } from 'translation-check';
...

class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    ...
    this.showTranslations = this.showTranslations.bind(this);
    ...
  }

  ...
  
  showTranslations() {
    showTranslations(i18n);
  }

  render() {
    ...
    return (
      <header>
        <Navbar color="light" light expand="md" fixed="top">
          ...
        </Navbar>
        <div>
          <button id="i18n" className="btn btn-sm" onClick={this.showTranslations}>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">...</svg>
          </button>
        </div>
      </header>
    );
  }
}

Header.propTypes = { isLoading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired };

export default Header;
```

The button `#i18n` has this simple `scss`:

```scss
#i18n {
  bottom: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

So, in practice, I position the button to open `locize/translation-check` in the bottom-left corner f the page.

Now, the problem is:

**Is there a way to import `locize/translation-check` only when in `development` env?**

The I could refactor the component to extract the rendering of the button, so I can include it only in `development` environment, but I suppose the error from ESLint will still remain as I will anyway import the `locize/translation-check`.

Is there a way to fix this issue without suppressing the error with a comment and without moving the dependency to the `dependencies` node in the `package.json`?